# What is the physical significance of negative frequencies?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency

This has been one of the holes in my cheddar cheese block of understanding DSP, so what is the physical interpretation of having a negative frequency?

If you have a physical tone at some frequency and it is DFT'd, you get a result in both the positive and negative frequencies - why and how does this occur? What does it mean?

Edit: Oct 18th 2011. I have provided my own answer, but expanded the question to include the roots of why negative frequencies MUST exist.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15539/negative-frequencies-what-is-that

Comment: Thanks endolith, would it be possible to cross link this page to them? I have provided an answer to my own question and would like to share it with that group too. I dont seem to have access to that area...

Comment: After reading all the physical significances of the negative frequencies, I got more confused. I am a chemist. I deal with molecules. The negatives frequencies indicate the instability in the molecules or, in other words, saddle points on the potential energy surface. A stable molecule should have no imaginary frequencies, a transition state should have one (1st order saddle point). Why not stable molecule should have negative frequencies (imaginary frequencies) after all it is the complementary to the real frequency.

Comment: @PrabinRai negative frequencies and imaginary frequencies are very different. An imaginary frequency turns an oscillating, bounded complex exponential into an exponentially increasing (or decreasing) ordinary exponential. A negative frequency, as the answers below indicate, refers to the "handedness" of the oscillation. They are still bounded functions, so I imagine it would still be "stable".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This has turned out to be quite the hot topic.

After reading the rich multitude of good and diverse opinions and interpretations and 
letting the issue simmer in my head for sometime, I believe I have a physical interpretation of the phenomenon of negative frequencies. And I believe the key interpretation here is that fourier is blind to time. Expaning on this further:

There has been a lot of talk about the 'direction' of the frequency, and thus how it can be 
+ve or -ve. While the overarching insights of the authors saying this is not lost, this 
statement is nontheless inconsistent with the definition of temporal frequency, so first we 
must define our terms very carefully. For example:

- *Distance* is a scalar (can only ever be +ve), while *displacement* is a vector. (ie, has 
  direction, can be +ve or -ve to illustrate heading).
- *Speed* is a scalar (can only be +ve), while *velocity* is a vector. (ie, again, has 
  direction, and can be +ve or -ve).

Thus by the same tokens,

- *Temporal Frequency* is a scalar, (can only be +ve)! Frequency is defined as number of 
  cycles per unit time. If this is the accepted definition, we **cannot** simply claim that it is going in 'a different direction'. Its a scalar after-all. Instead, we must define a new term - the vector equivalent of frequency. Perhaps 'angular frequency' would be the right terminology here, and indeed, that is precisely what a *digital* frequency measures.

Now all the sudden we are in the business of measuring number of *rotations* per unit time, 
(a vector quantity that can have direction), VS just the number of repititions of some physical oscillation.

Thus when we are asking about the physical interpretation of negative frequencies, we are 
also implicitly asking about **how** the scalar and very real measures of number of 
oscillations per unit time of some physical phenomenon like waves on a beach, sinusoidal AC 
current over a wire, *map* to this angular-frequency that now all the sudden happens to have direction, either clockwise or counterclockwise.

From here, to arrive at a physical interpretation of negative frequencies two facts need to 
be heeded. The first one is that as Fourier pointed out, an oscillatory real tone with 
*scalar temporal frequency, f*, can be constructed by adding two oscillatory complex tones, 
with *vector angular frequencies, +w and -w* together.

$$
\cos(\omega_0 t)=\frac{e^{\jmath \omega_0t}+e^{-\jmath \omega_0 t}}{2}
$$

Thats great, but so what? Well, the complex tones are rotating in directions opposite to 
each other. (See also Sebastian's comment). But what is the significance of the 'directions' here that give our angular frequencies their vector status? What physical quantity is being reflected in the direction of rotation? The answer is time. In the first complex tone, time is travelling in the +ve direction, and in the second complex tone, time is travelling in the -ve direction. Time is going backwards.

Keeping this in mind and taking a quick diversion to recall that temporal frequency is the 
first derivative of phase with respect to time, (simply the change of phase over time), everything begins to fall into place:

**The physical interpretation of negative frequencies is as follows:**

My first realization was that *fourier is time-agnostic*. That is, if you think about it, 
there is nothing in fourier analysis or the transform itself that can tell you what the 
'direction' of time is. Now, imagine a physically oscillating system (ie a real sinusoid 
from say, a current over a wire) that is oscillating at some *scalar temporal-frequency, f*.

Imagine 'looking' down this wave, in the forwards direction of time as it progresses. Now 
imagine calculating its difference in phase at every point in time you progress further. 
This will give you your scalar temporal frequency, and your frquency is positive. So far so 
good.

But wait a minute - if fourier is blind to time, then why should it only consider your wave 
in the 'forward' time direction? There is nothing special about that direction in time. Thus by symmetry, the other direction of time must also be considered. Thus now imagine 'looking' up at the same wave, (ie, *backwards* in time), and also performing the same delta-phase calculation. Since time is going backwards now, and your frequency is change-of-phase/(negative time), your frequency will now be negative!

What Fourier is really saying, is that this signal has energy if played forward in time at 
frequency bin f, but ALSO has energy if played *backwards* in time albeit at frequency bin 
-f. In a sense it MUST say this because fourier has no way of 'knowing' what the 'true' 
direction of time is!

So how does fourier capture this? Well, in order to show the *direction* of time, a rotation of some sort *must* be employed such that a clockwise roation dealinates 'looking' at the signal in the forward arrow of time, and a counterclockwise roation dealinates 'looking' at the signal as if time was going backwards. The scalar temporal frequency we are all familiar with should now be equal to the (scaled) absolute value of our vector angular frequency. But how can a point signifying the displacement of a sinusoid wave arrive at its starting point after one cycle yet simultaneously rotate around a circle and maintain a manifestation of the temporal frequency it signifies? Only if the major axes of that circle are composed of measuring displacement of this point relative to the original sinusoid, and a sinusoid off by 90 degrees. (This is exactly how fourier gets his sine and cosine bases the you project against every time you perform a DFT!). And finally, how do we keep those axes seperate? The 'j' guarantees that the magnitude on each axis is always independant of the magnitude on the other, since real and imaginary numbers cannot be added to yield a new number in either domain. (But this is just a side note).

Thus in summary:

The fourier transform is time-agnostic. It cannot tell the direction of time. This is at the heart of negative frequencies. Since frequency = phase-change/time, anytime you take the DFT of a signal, fourier is saying that if time was going forwards, your energy is located on the +ve frequency axis, but if your time was going backwards, your energy is located on the -ve frequency axis.

As our universe has [shown before](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Time_reversal_symmetry&redirect=no), it is precisely because Fourier does not know the direction of time, that both sides of the DFT *must* be symmetric, and why the existence of negative frequencies are necessary and in fact very real indeed.

Comment: I think you're reading a bit too much into this in an attempt to justify an answer that you already have decided upon. The roots of "negative" frequencies have been pointed out in other answers. The Fourier transform uses complex exponentials as its basis functions. Their complex nature makes it possible to discriminate the sign of the exponential's frequency as time increases. Complex exponentials are of interest because they are [eigenfunctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenfunction) of linear time-invariant systems. That makes the FT very useful as an signal and systems analysis tool.

Comment: The negative frequencies that exist in the complex-exponential decomposition of signals are part of the package that comes along with using the Fourier transform. There is no need to come up with a complicated, qualitative explanation for what they must mean.

Comment: Also, I think your first bullet might be in error; I've always heard *distance* referred to as a scalar, while *displacement* is a vector quantity.

Comment: Also, in addition to what Jason said, I really fail to see the "physical" aspect in this answer, that _you_ said was lacking in all the others...

Comment: @JasonR I know my post is long, but please *do* try to read my post (fully) before commenting on it in the future. When you do you will see that it is not complicated but fits nicely with what we know so far. You will see how my explanation is actually *derived* and *built* from all the prior answers and my research into the literature.

Comment: @JasonR Going back to the subject at hand, I have shown how negative frequencies have to be interpreted in the context of interpreted of time flowing backwards, with one main reason being that frequency is nothing but the rate of change of phase over time, and the only way for this to occur is for time to flow backwards given a constant delta-phase.

Comment: @JasonR A sinusoid is the sum of two phasors, one of which rotates clockwise, the other one of which rotates counter clockwise. One helix was drawn earlier as it evolved in time. If the other helix it is being added to is rotating in the opposite direction, this means it is evolving backwards in time. This is where the 'negative' comes from.

Comment: @yoda See last comment for physical aspect. Physically, the signal is 'looked at' as if time was reversed, the first derivative of its phase changes computed with time flowing in the reverse direction. When it is projected onto the bases of fourier, this fact must be reflected this fourier is blind to time. Also, please provide a quote on what you claim I said.

Comment: you've come full circle with this answer and arrived at where we began.  Negative frequencies shouldn't seem any odder than the negative numbers and negatively labelled x-y planes we were using in grade school.  Mathematics doesn't care and never has, that the Fourier transform conforms to this is really not that surprising.   Math always allowed time to "flow backwards" so why shouldn't the universe?  Hardly more *physical* than the common sense "opposite spin" answer,  but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Even if time moves forward, any rotating object can move in clockwise or anti clockwise direction. No need for time to go backwards. Fourier can sense the direction of time, it's called $time shifting$ property. If there is no sense of direction with respect to time, then there won't be any time shifting property.

Answer (score 151):

Negative frequency doesn't make much sense for sinusoids, but the Fourier transform doesn't break up a signal into sinusoids, it breaks it up into [complex exponentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) (also called "complex sinusoids" or "[cisoid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cisoid)s"):

$$F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \color{Red}{e^{- j\omega t}}\,dt$$

These are actually spirals, spinning around in the complex plane:

[image: complex exponential showing time and real and imaginary axes]

([Source: Richard Lyons](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261779218_Understanding_Digital_Signal_Processing's_Frequency_Domain))

Spirals can be either left-handed or right-handed (rotating clockwise or counterclockwise), which is where the concept of negative frequency comes from.  You can also think of it as the phase angle going forward or backward in time.

In the case of real signals, there are always *two* equal-amplitude complex exponentials, rotating in opposite directions, so that their real parts combine and imaginary parts cancel out, leaving only a real sinusoid as the result.  This is why the spectrum of a sine wave always has 2 spikes, one positive frequency and one negative.  Depending on the phase of the two spirals, they could cancel out, leaving a purely real sine wave, or a real cosine wave, or a purely imaginary sine wave, etc.

The negative and positive frequency components *are* both necessary to produce the real signal, but if you already know that it's a real signal, the other side of the spectrum doesn't provide any extra information, so it's often hand-waved and ignored.  For the general case of complex signals, you need to know both sides of the frequency spectrum.

Comment: I like that description; I think the diagram explains it well.

Comment: @endolith Nice post - I have seen this from Lyons book btw. It would seem to me that the actual 'starting' point for all oscillations is in the complex domain, and that it just so happens that we can only measure realistic oscillations that occur on the real-axis. So when a physical wave is measured, it is taken BACK into the complex domain, which is where we see its clockwise and counter-clock wise components. Which is funny because 'real' signals end up being 'twice as complicated' as complex signals...

Comment: @Mohammad: I don't know about complex exponentials being more "fundamental" than sinusoids in general, though they are in the case of the Fourier transform.  You can produce complex exponentials by adding sinusoids, and sinusoids by adding complex exponentials.  They're all just functions.  Sinusoids are generally derived from circles, which may be something in the complex plane, or may just be the height of a dot on a spinning wheel.

Comment: @endolith Right. I have expanded on that some in my post. Either way great post (and thanks for the cross link). Have an upvote! :-)

Comment: I've tried to make animations of this ([1](https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5642/21110449901_cfe0829e4f_o_d.gif) [2](https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5832/21092661362_b3c50e715d_o_d.gif)), but [couldn't figure out how to crop the subplots in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31888825/125507):

Comment: I don't see where the diagram factors in the negative frequency. Does it?

Comment: @Goldname The diagram shows a cisoid with positive frequency.  A cisoid with negative frequency looks the same, but rotating in the opposite direction.

Comment: But I cannot imagine how another cisoid rotating in the opposite direction that somehow flattens out by canceling out the imaginary sinusoid but preserving the real sinusoid.

Comment: @Goldname The positive and negative frequency cisoids are added together.  The real parts are in phase and sum together, the imaginary parts are opposite polarity, and cancel out

Comment: Yeah but I'm not visualizing it. A positive cisoid + a negative cisoid that are completely overlapping would be 0 all throughout from what I can see.

Comment: @Goldname Are these helpful at all? https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5642/21110449901_cfe0829e4f_o.gif https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5832/21092661362_b3c50e715d_o.gif https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5664/20914841898_163ae8dc99_o.gif

Comment: Thanks, these are pretty helpful. I guess it somehow works out in the end by cancelling

Comment: Is this how information is conserved by the FFT? Meaning, a (periodic or windowed) function sampled N times is represented by N real values. If you perform FFT on it, you will get N complex values, meaning 2N real components. But if half of them are implied, you can throw them out and are left again with N real components?

Comment: @Tobia You can only throw them out if the original signal is real.  If the original signal is complex, then the spectrum is not symmetrical.  If your signal is 10 real values, then the FFT output is 10 real values + 10 imaginary values. So it carries twice as much information as necessary.  But if your original signal is 10 real + 10 imaginary, the FFT output is also 10 real + 10 imaginary, it contains the same amount of information.

Comment: This is one of the best explanations I've ever seen on Stack Exchange 

Answer (score 52):

Let's say you had a spinning wheel. How would you describe how fast it is spinning? You'd probably say it's spinning at `X` revolutions per minute (rpm). Now how do you convey in what *direction* it's spinning with this number? It's the same `X` rpm if it's spinning clockwise or anti-clockwise. So you scratch your head and say oh well, here's a smart idea: I'll use the convention of `+X` to indicate that it's spinning clockwise and `-X` for anti-clockwise. Voila! You've invented negative rpms!

---

Negative frequency is no different from the above simple example. A simple mathematical explanation of how the negative frequency pops up can be seen from the Fourier transforms of pure tone sinusoids.

Consider the Fourier transform pair of a complex sinusoid: $e^{\jmath \omega_0 t}\longleftrightarrow \delta(\omega+\omega_0)$ (ignoring constant multiplier terms). For a pure sinusoid (real), we have from Euler's relation:

$$\cos(\omega_0 t)=\frac{e^{\jmath \omega_0t}+e^{-\jmath \omega_0 t}}{2}$$

and hence, its Fourier transform pair (again, ignoring constant multipliers):

$$\cos(\omega_0 t)\longleftrightarrow \delta(\omega+\omega_0) + \delta(\omega-\omega_0)$$

You can see that it has two frequencies: a positive one at $\omega_0$ and a negative one at $-\omega_0$ by definition! The complex sinusoid of $ae^{\jmath \omega_0 t}$ is widely used because it is incredibly useful in simplifying our mathematical calculations. However, it has only one frequency and a real sinusoid actually has two.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I understand the math - and this is something basic I know of, but it doesnt give us information on the physical meaning... Going on your spinning example though - ok, so the sign of the frequency conveys the 'direction' of the change in phase. Fair enough, but still, why does a sinusoid have 'two' frequencies, one positive and one negative? Is it because the fourier transform is 'time agnostic', and so you can look at a real sinusoid in the real direction of time, get your +ve, and look at the same wave backwards in time and get your -ve? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a concrete answer to your confusion. Content at negative frequencies is a consequence of the definition of the Fourier transform and doesn't directly have a physical meaning. The Fourier transform isn't inherently a "physical" operation, so it doesn't have to. A sinusoid's frequency is the time derivative of phase, nothing more. Negative frequencies are just a mathematical artifact that some people get hung up on, similar to the use of "imaginary" parts of complex numbers. They are analysis tools used for modeling, not necessarily existing in the physical world.

Comment: @Mohammad I agree with Jason here. At some point, trying to construct a "physical" explanation for the sake of it can only make things worse. I'm not sure I can explain any better...

Comment: ...Umm, the hallmark of science is to attach physical meaning to reality and the math we use to describe it. It doesnt make anything 'worse'. I got the same response from professors talking about "complex band pass signals", until we realized imaginary components are just the quadrature of your signal, and the real components are the in-phase. That is a physical interpretation of complex signals. So I am asking, what is the physical interpretation of the negative frequencies? You interpret the positive side to tell you your rate of oscillation, what does the -ve tell you?

Comment: @Jason also I disagree it is something people 'get hung up on' - I have seem many algorithms suppress negative frequencies over positive ones for some goal, or asymmetrical use of +ve and -ve frequencies. One way of computing a hilbert transform centers on this. It has physical repercussions you can be sure of that. You mentioned tools for modelling - what does a negative frequency model?

Comment: @Mohammad The part about "suppressing" negative frequencies is addressed in my answer. By using a complex sinusoid, you're effectively disregarding the negative frequency. I'll try to think of something simpler to explain.

Comment: A possible explanation is that from the point of the Fourier transform, a real sinusoid is "really" the sum of two complex sinusoids spinning in opposite directions. Using the wheel analogy: Picture two wheels at the origin of a coordinate system, spinning at the same speed but in opposite directions, with a pin on each that starts at (1,0). Now add the coordinates of both pins: y will always be 0, and x will be a real sinusoid.

Comment: @SebastianReichelt Thanks, that is exactly what I was trying to convey by writing $\cos(x)$ as a sum of two complex exponentials. I'll edit it to make the point clearer

Comment: @SebastianReichelt yes, from the POV of fourier a real sinusoid is the sum of two complex sinusoids - this is true - the challenge is to attach this meaning to real-life. It seems that the real-axis captures a 'real' sinusoid that we can observe/measure in reality. What does the imaginary axis capture vis-a-vis reality?

Comment: @Mohammad What do imaginary numbers represent to you, in a physical sense?

Comment: @yoda Actually, (and I am going to touch on this in my answer), the sqrt(-1) or j as we know it in EE terms, can be interpreted as simply a number multiplied to a real number such that that product is not subject to operations with other real numbers anymore. In this way, you can get orthogonal spaces.

Comment: @Mohammad You've merely given me a mathematical definition. What's a physical apples and oranges definition?

Comment: @yoda They cannot be used to 'count' quantities if that is what you are after, however they can be used as tools in the counting of quantities.

Comment: @Mohammad No, that's not what I'm after. I'm merely trying to understand how you interpret imaginary numbers "physically", so that I can perhaps try and explain things in that basis.

Comment: @yoda As I have already said, j is interpreted 'physically' as a label. It separates numbers on one axis from being muddled up with numbers on another axis.

Comment: @SebastianReichelt Or mount one wheel on the rim of the other wheel, to "add" their rotations.  A point on the rim of the second counter-rotating wheel will just move up and down

Answer (score 20):

Currently, my viewpoint (it is subject to change) is the following

For sinusoidal repetition only positive frequencies makes sense. The physical interpretation is clear.
For complex exponential repetition both positive and negative frequencies makes sense. It may be possible to attach a physical interpretation to negative frequency. That physical interpretation of negative frequency has to do with direction of repetition.

The definition of frequency as provided on wiki is: "Frequency is the number of occurrences of a repeating event per unit time"

If sticking to this definition negative frequency does not make sense and therefore has no physical interpretation. However, this definition of frequency is not thorough for complex exponential repetition which can also have direction.

Negative frequencies are used all the time when doing signal or system analysis. The fundamental reason for this being the Euler formula $$e^{j\omega n} = \cos( \omega n) + j\, \sin(\omega n)$$ and the fact that complex exponentials are eigenfunctions of LTI systems.

The sinusoidal repetition is normally of interest and the complex exponential repetition is often used to obtain the sinusoidal repetition indirectly. That the two are related can be easily seen by considering the Fourier representation written using complex exponentials e.g.
$$ x[n]= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\!\!\!d\omega  \;\;\;\;X(e^{j\omega}) e^{j\omega n}  $$

However, this is equivalent to

$$ x[n] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}\!\!d\omega  \;\;[a(\omega) \cos(\omega n) + b(\omega) \sin(\omega n)] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}\!\!d\omega  \;\; \alpha(\omega) \sin(\omega n + \phi(\omega))] $$

So instead of considering a positive 'sinusoidal frequency axis', a negative and positive 'complex exponential frequency axis' is considered.
On the 'complex exponential frequency axis', for real signals, it is well known that the negative frequency part is redundant and only the positive 'complex exponential frequency axis' is considered. In making this step implicitly we know that the frequency axis represents complex exponential repetition and not sinusoidal repetition.

The complex exponential repetition is a circular rotation in the complex plane. In order to create a sinusoidal repetition it takes two complex exponential repetitions, one repetition clock-wise and one repetition counter clock-wise. 
If a physical device is constructed that produces a sinusoidal repetition inspired by how the sinusoidal repetition is created in the complex plane, that is, by two physically rotating devices that rotates in opposite directions, one of the rotating devices can be said to have a negative frequency and thereby the negative frequency has a physical interpretation.

Comment: I like your explanation... slowly a picture is emerging, see my answer / edit-to-question.

Answer (score 12):

In many common applications negative frequencies have no direct physical meaning at all. Consider a case where there is an input and an output voltage in some electrical circuit with resistors, capacitors, and inductors. There is simply a real input voltage with one frequency and there is a single output voltage with the same frequency but different amplitude and phase.

The ONLY reason why you would consider complex signals, complex Fourier Transforms and phasor math at this point is mathematically convenience. You could do it just as well with entirely real math, it would just be a lot harder.

There are different types of time/frequency transforms. The Fourier Transform uses a complex exponential as its basis function and applied to a single real-valued sine wave happens to produces a two valued results which is interpreted as positive and negative frequency. There are other transforms (like the Discrete Cosine Transform) which would not produce any negative frequencies at all. Again, it’s a matter of mathematical convenience; the Fourier Transform is often the quickest and most efficient way to solve a specific problem.

Comment: I agree, it is certainly a lot more convenient to work in the complex domain - the 'issue' creeps up because some individuals claim that there is no physical meaning to negative frequencies, yet somehow they possess energy in the frequency domain. Well, if they aren't 'really there', then where is this energy?

Answer (score 8):

even though everything important has been said I wanted to add some code and more visual keys on why the following formulas require positve and negative frequencies to make clear that negative frequencies are important for canceling out the counterparts in the inverse dft.

So lets see for

$\sin z = \frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}} \left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z} - \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}z} \right)$

$\cos z = \frac{1}{2} \left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z} + \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}z} \right)$

lets first produce a complex sinusoids and plot it:

```
# sine wave parameters
freq = 1;    # frequency in Hz
ampl = 1;    # amplitude in a.u.
phas = 0; # phase in radians

# generate the sine wave
pos_csw = ampl * np.exp( 1j* (2*np.pi * freq * time + phas) );
neg_csw = ampl * np.exp( 1j* (2*np.pi * (- freq ) * time + phas) );

# plot the results
plt.plot(time,np.real(pos_csw),label='real')
plt.plot(time,np.imag(pos_csw),label='imag')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec.)'), plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Complex positive freq sine wave projections')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# plot the results
plt.plot(time,np.real(neg_csw),label='real')
plt.plot(time,np.imag(neg_csw),label='imag')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec.)'), plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Complex negative freq sine wave projections')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# now show in 3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot(time,np.real(pos_csw),np.imag(pos_csw))
ax.plot(time,np.real(neg_csw),np.imag(neg_csw))

ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)'), ax.set_ylabel('Real part'), ax.set_zlabel('Imag part')
ax.set_title('Complex sine wave in all its 3D glory')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

now for computing `cosine = pos_csw + neg_csw` results in

[image]

[image]

---

while computing `sine = pos_csw - neg_csw` results in:

[image]

[image]

So dividing by 2 is necessary because the not canceling factors add the same values to each other and dividing by i for sine is necessary to become real.

Answer (score 6):

You should study the Fourier transform or series to understand the negative frequency. Indeed Fourier showed that we can show all of waves using some sinusoids. Each sinusoid can be shown with two peaks at the frequency of this wave one in positive side and one in negative. So the theoretical reason is clear. But for the physical reason, I always see that people say negative frequency has just mathematical meaning. But I guess a physical interpretation that I'm not pretty sure; When you study the circular motion as the principal of discussions about the waves, the direction of speed of the movement on the half-circle is inverse of the another half. This can be the reason why we have two peaks in both sides of the frequency domain for each sine wave.

Comment: Hossein, yes, I agree it had be confused for a while. I am waiting on yoda for his feedback, but if it is just simply the sign of the derivative of the phase, then I see a linguistic problem - perhaps the source of confusion with the many other folks I have talked to about this as well.

The physical meaning of a 'frequency' is 'the rate of oscillation' of something, meaning is has to be positive. This is where I think the definitions differ from that in physics.

Comment: Please look at the page en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion; $w=2∗π/T$ and $f=1/T$ so f and w have direct relation. In each wave, the direction of speed is changed to have a complete oscillation. We always should take care that a real wave needs two rates to be a complete one. In practice when you work with spectrum analyzer, you've just positive part because it is sufficient. The negative part is quite meaningful because in case of the shift, you can see this negative part on spectrum analyzer that shows just positive parts.

Answer (score 5):

What is the meaning of negative distance?  One possibility is that it's for continuity, so you don't have to flip planet Earth upside down every time you walk across the equator, and want to plot your position North with a continuous 1st derivative.

Same with frequency, when one might do such things as FM modulation with a modulation wider than the carrier frequency.   How would you plot that?

Comment: See my new answer / edit to question

Answer (score 5):

An easy way of thinking about the problem is to imaging a standing wave. The standing wave (in time domain) can be represented as a sum of two oppositely moving traveling waves (in frequency domain with positive and negative k vector, or +w and -w which is equivalent). Here comes the answer on why you have two frequency components in the FFT. FFT is basically a sum (convolution) of many of such oppositely traveling waves that represent your function in time domain.

Answer (score 5):

**In the real World, actual event frequency is fundamentally unsigned**

Frequency is measured in Hz, which is defined as the inverse of the second, and is used to count how often an event repeats. Time is assumed to flow only towards the future, thus for a periodic event, period $\small T$ is fundamentally an unsigned quantity, and frequency $\small f=1/T$ is therefore fundamentally unsigned.

**Negative frequency sinusoid: Mixing with frequency of the complex exponential**

Talking about a sinusoidal waveform with a negative frequency is inaccurate. We are mixing the sinusoid waveform with its usual mathematical breakdown into a handy sum of complex exponentials: $\small \cos(\omega t) = \frac {1} {2} e^{j\omega t} + \frac {1} {2} e^{-j\omega t}$ of same and opposite frequencies, $\small \omega$ and $\small -\omega$.

Indeed one of the complex exponentials has a negative frequency, still the term of this mathematical breakdown cannot be transposed into the physical world. In DSP, this complex exponential exists only as a sequence of numbers. To reach the real world, and represent an actual phenomenon, it must be converted into a physical signal (a waveform), e.g. using a DAC. A DAC just takes either the real or the imaginary part of the complex sequence, both are regular sinusoids where the notion of negative frequency is meaningless (see picture below).

Negative frequencies are similar to the square root of -1, they are only handy mathematical concepts, but they have no physical counterparts.

**Negative sign is often a convention, not a physical property**

Using negative frequencies is not different than using other negative quantities.

E.g. we can measure a room occupancy by looking at people entering and leaving the room, counting the former positively and the latter negatively. The number of people in the room is the sum. It would be meaningless to find a difference between people, based on "their sign", because this sign is a methodological one, artificially defined.

Negative frequencies are only that. An observer may declare a wheel turns at 10 Hz or at -10 Hz. The unsigned value 10 represents something real, the measured angular velocity, but the sign is only a convention from the observer. If the observer looks from the other side of the wheel, the sign might change while the wheel still rotates the same way. The convention may be different for another observer. On a car, do the wheels turn at a positive or a negative rate?

**Negative frequency: Blame Euler**

From [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) we know sinusoids, sines and cosines, can be split into two complex carriers of opposite frequencies, multiplied by conjugate phasors. The carriers are functions of time. ([More about phasor and carrier](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/Phasor_Carrier_Components_Sinusoids.html)).

$\small A\cos(\omega t +\phi) = Ae^{j \phi} \times \frac {1} {2} e^{j\omega t} + Ae^{-j \phi} \times \frac {1} {2} e^{-j\omega t}$

The carriers can be represented as helices, turning at the angular velocity defined by their frequency. If the frequency sign are different, the helices turn in opposite directions:

[image]
[image]

From the pictures, we see each helix can be split into two sinusoids, which are nothing else than the helix real and imaginary parts. The phasors only determines the amplitude and the starting angle (phase at time t=0).

To match Euler's formula, the frequencies and the start angels must be exactly opposite and the amplitude must be identical. In that case:

- The carriers turn at the same velocity, the vertical sinusoids are opposite and cancel each other when added.
- On the other hand, the horizontal sinusoids are in phase, and when added result in a sinusoid with amplitude doubled.

This breakdown of cosine function into conjugate phasors/carriers is massively used in Fourier transform used to convert a signal into its spectral components. FT being a basic operation in signal processing, negative frequencies are always present.

However as mentioned, we must be careful: The possibility of this mathematical breakdown of a sinusoid doesn't mean it has a physical equivalence, these helices don't exist physically. The only real thing in the signal is the starting point: A sinusoidal variation with its unsigned frequency.

**Negative frequencies in a spectrum**

The principle of the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is to find the phasors associated with a series of carriers. Note the DFT doesn't compute the sample values for the carriers, it just *assumes* the carrier frequencies are symmetrical about zero (conjugates), are in the same number than the samples in the input, are spaced by the inverse of the sampling rate and have all a unit amplitude. The DFT rather computes the phasors which, in this context, are called the spectral coefficients. Each phasor is the complex exponential corresponding to the amplitude and phase at time zero of a carrier.

For an input which is real-valued (e.g. samples from a physical sensor), conjugate carriers have conjugate phasors. So these two spectral components nicely sum up into a cosine of twice the amplitude and the same (unsigned) frequency.

But we do not need this property to explain why negative frequencies are not found into the real world. After all we can build mathematical signals with negative frequencies from scratch, where the conjugate carriers don't have conjugate coefficients, or we can mathematically shift a symmetrical spectrum entirely to the negative side by a simple multiplication with a mathematical sinusoid of negative frequency.

The very reason these signals cannot reach the real world is a rotating phasor has no actual existence, in DSP it's only numbers, in analog SP it exists as two separate sinusoidal sources. This fictive phasor must be converted from its digital or dual form into a single analog waveform. So the engineer must find a way to convert the virtual helix into a regular sinusoid at some point, prior to the conversion. This regular sinusoid puts a halt to the mathematical negative sign, which never reaches the real world.

Comment: -1, a rotating phasor _does_ have associated physical phenomena, and the arguments under the section are unsound. "no difference except time shift" is incorrect, no shifting of one relative to other will create a match. The visuals are nice but substance flawed.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon/ Thanks for the comment. I think you misunderstood my point, a rotating phasor is a mathematical tool, not a physical phenomena, and shifting a sinusoid will match another sinusoid of the same frequency (I'm not talking about compound signals here).

Comment: Your writing reads as "$+f$ is $-f$ within a time-shift", which isn't correct. Also all of math is "mathematical, not physical", defeating the purpose of discussion in this sense.

Comment: I guess you meant $f$ as in a real-valued sinusoid input, but first that could be worded better as it immediately follows phasors discussion, and second it doesn't support the claim anyway as the full FT operates on complex inputs and "complex" != "nonphysical".

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: I cannot find that wording, perhaps you're referring to "*Maybe the sinusoids represent a physical phenomena, like the variation of luminosity at a certain point in space. If they do, it's clear there is nothing special when they are extracted from a negative frequency rotating phasor. There is no difference, except a time shift.*". Which seems correct to me. Pure sinusoids can be taken from the rotating phasors of frequency $-f$ or $+f$. They have both a frequency $+f$, hence they can be matched by time shifting.

Comment: Right, hence my followup comment. I did misread it, my mistake, but with intent to favor the argument.

Comment: I do see / understand why many associate sine waves more with the real world than a complex phasor but not sure I agree with that. I see a sine wave as a mathematical tool (abstraction as well) as well.  I can describe physical phenomenon with sine waves $\sin(\theta)$ as well as $e^{j\theta}$ and I build physical hardware with complex signals (just because we need to real numbers to describe a single complex number does not make the complex number any more or less "real" than a real number.) Once we create numbers, both are mathematical abstractions or tools.

Comment: "in analog SP it exists as two separate sinusoidal sources." Note that that detail is the same on paper or analysis: a complex number is represented by two real numbers (either I+jQ, or magnitude and phase). So does that mean complex numbers don't exist in analysis?

Comment: @DanBoschen: As often said, "the map is not the territory". We model the universe using numbers, still numbers have no physical existence, they are human concepts and we can make them tell anything. We can measure "time" with stopwatches, but [time existence is challended](https://theconversation.com/time-might-not-exist-according-to-physicists-and-philosophers-but-thats-okay-181268). The representation of a frequency by a negative number doesn't imply a negative frequency is meaningful. See [reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(fallacy)).

Comment: @mins exactly! Except for the meaningful part (as it is indeed meaningful, and useful, for me) but agreed numbers exist as themselves for what they are and what we make them, whether they are “real” or “imaginary”. That naming itself is most unfortunate :) Thanks for your comment and glad you see my point.

Comment: @DanBoschen: We also agree on your last point, I don't say negative frequencies in the mathematical model are meaningless or not useful, just that the model cannot be transposed as-is in the real world, the sign needs some physical interpretation. This is similar to a model with [negative pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_room_pressure). Negative pressure cannot  exist. This is a positive pressure on the outer side of the pressure vessel (the differential is negative).

Comment: A bicycle wheel rotating counter clockwise vs clockwise may be an example of frequency with a direction?  My more direct physical interpretation is a phase that is decreasing vs time is a negative frequency (freq is the derivative of phase), and phase increasing vs time is a positive frequency. Often this is relative to a carrier as a relative frequency (neg or positive) but can equally be relative to DC (as long as we use two real signals to represent it)!

Answer (score 1):

The significance is **s p i n**

[image]

---

*(The first part of this answer assumes familiarity with complex "spin"; supplementary explanations are referenced at bottom, and should be consulted *before* reading the main body if one's unfamiliar.)*

Spectral asymmetry is spin asymmetry. Negatives dominating positives guarantees net-clockwise traversal about the axis of evolution (which is also the axis of revolution), and vice versa.

One can have all the ingredients, but the missing piece can be the right perspective. The key is to recognize that spin is a **separate degree of freedom**.

The Fourier transform collapses the time axis and only speaks of frequencies. Its ability to directly represent variation, in that behavior is read off directly from coefficients faithfully, does not extend to frequencies or amplitudes that change over time. More generally, we have time-frequency, whose coefficients directly represent frequency and amplitude over time - in best case exactly, in worst case bounded by Heisenberg's uncertainty. Within it, positives are negatives are both more distinct and more natural:

[image]
[image]

We have what can be described as pulses - bursts of oscillations - and a usual spectrogram, except also showing negatives, and this time the intensities aren't mirrored as for real-valued signals. Each half of the spectrogram responds to unique variation.

Indeed, lack of mirroring guarantees the signal isn't real-valued. This may be a surprise - per conventional wisdom of STFT modulus discarding phase, one may figure we can mirror *magnitude* but have phase be not Hermitian-symmetric. But we can't! To do so would mean we have counter-clockwise and clockwise traversal over same time instants, which by definition cancel. The only alternatives are complete sign reversal, which cancels to zero, or aligned rotation, which doubles up either on positives or negatives. Indeed, STFT isn't FT, and its modulus is strongly invertible (within global phase shift) - if such mirroring were possible, much more info would be lost.

More yet, CWT says positives and negatives are infinitely apart. In an important sense, CWT is the one with fixed resolution, not STFT - and follows ratio-based (logarithmic) decomposition, more natural for many structures. If we try to cross from negatives to positives, with linear frequency growth, we see:

[image]
[image]

The traversal *stops*, momentarily. This is required, since we're crossing the DC bin, which is of course the constant bin with zero derivative - and it further shows the fundamental distinction: no amount of speeding up or slowing down, or changing of intensity, results in changed direction of rotation.

The morale is simple: spin encodes **irreducible** variation that is inexpressible in terms of frequency - rate of oscillation - or amplitude - intensity of oscillation. As a more familiar analogy, it's like using a microphone that only records volume, without frequency: no matter how we do it, volume is just volume - an entire degree of freedom is missing.

So what's it all mean? What of the "real world"?

The real world:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Vsauce](https://youtu.be/IJhgZBn-LHg)</sup>

The world orbits the sun, the sun orbits [Sagittarius A*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sagittarius_A*) - in turn, our Earth traverses a helix about the sun's orbit. If we take January 1 to be 0 degrees with respect to the sun and start recording, then by December 31, the Earth will traverse [358.77 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWmPg.png) [counterclockwise](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Earth%27s_orbit#Media/File:Motion_of_Sun,_Earth_and_Moon_around_the_Milky_Way.jp) about the sun with a mean radius of [149,600,000 km](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Astronomical_unit), and [7,233,408,000 km](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Earth%27s_orbit#Media/File:Motion_of_Sun,_Earth_and_Moon_around_the_Milky_Way.jpg) with respect to Saggitarius A*. The Discrete Fourier Transform of this path peaks at [$+3.16 \times 10^{-8}\ \text{Hz}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjgKy.png), with amplitude of around 149,600,000 km, and no negative frequencies.

If aliens hand us a graph of the complete Fourier transform of Earth's orbit (and cite relativity for how they saw future paths), and the graph shows a peak at a negative frequency, we'll ask if they have room aboard.

If we want to compare slinkies, or springs,

[image]

<sup>Source: [sparktec, e-Bay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/325448170411)</sup>

If the spring on left is meant to be inserted from the wide end, then its Fourier transform peaks negative (clockwise), else positive. If we want coiling with even spacing, we can check if there's multiple peaks close in amplitude, as with springs on right. If we want windings to have the same radius, or compare spacings between windings, we can look at their spectrogram, which is a locally weighted unfolding of the Fourier transform along time, that'll reveal the instantaneous radius and rate of winding over the length of the spring.

If we want to measure the performance of an all-terrain vehicle (ATV),

[image]

<sup>Source: [carbuzz.com](https://carbuzz.com/features/most-extreme-all-terrain-vehicles-on-the-planet)</sup>

the 2D Fourier transform (rather, 3D spectrogram) of a recording of a point on the wheel over time, and over distance the ATV travels on muddy roads, will reveal the efficiency with which the wheels' rotations result in actual motion as opposed to fighting the mud (distance vs time amplitude), and we can compare performance for different wheel speeds (frequency), and when the car is going forward vs backwards (negative vs positive frequency).

The list goes on. Now, some may object. Yet, the "metaphysical status" of complex numbers bears no difference. The positive and negative frequencies of the Fourier transform meaningfully and usefully describe physical phenomena, and each is distinct and necessary for a complete description.

#### I still don't buy it! Where's *real* imaginary numbers?

Fine. Actually, in your ears:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/inner-ear)</sup>

The [Joint Time-Frequency Scattering](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78623/50076) transform  shares bioplausibility with STRF (Spectro-Temporal Receptive Fields), where close correspondence with auditory responses of animals and humans is shown by neurophysiological and behavioral evidence ([V. Lostanlen, et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.10926v2.pdf), [D. Klein, et al](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10946994/), [F. Theunissen, et al](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10704507/)). Methods include comparing direct measurements of auditory cortex responses with the model's coefficients to a range of stimuli, and correlating perceptual recognition of human listeners of musical sounds with nearest neighbor search directly on coefficients. [T. Chi, et al](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1121/1.1945807) estimate $Q_2 \approx 2$ (one of key transform parameters) in humans.

It's a fundamentally complex transform. It applies complex 2D wavelets upon the modulus of complex wavelet transform to discriminate rises and falls in frequency. The input is standard real-valued audio, but its projection to complex space is necessary to obtain the discriminatory, invariance, and stability properties of the transform that are responsible for the notable success of its features fed straight to a linear classifier on audio tasks. The linear classifier is the final stage of nearly all modern machine learning methods; success of fed features indicates that the relevant variability is distributed in such a way in the transformed space that distinct classes are grouped left and right (for example) and can be picked out by naked eye - or in short, strong explanatory power.

Simply put, there's strong evidence for the ear doing equivalently complex-valued processing. As for where exactly it happens, physically, I'm no cochlea expert at all.

What's required, physically, for distinct use of negative frequencies and complex numbers, is three degrees of freedom - with two of said degrees evolving in terms of the third, while forming a pair for which "angle" is a valid parameter. This is *suggestive* of rotation, and while valid rotational interpretation directly follows, something physically rotating is not required - the rotation can instead take place in the resulting projection, for example electric and magnetic components of an EM wave. Of course, physical circular behavior (not necessarily over time) is ideal.

#### No matter what you say, imaginary isn't real

Is negative real? Can you hold negative two apples?

"I can have debt, that's negative money" - no, that's what the banker says to remove your positive money. Indeed, that's what "negative" *means* - a quantity such that, when combined with a positive of equal size, cancels.

An imaginary is a quantity such that, when squared and combined with a real squared, cancels.

Imaginaries "exist" as much as reals do. They don't, or they do. The name is what I consider to be the greatest misnomer in all of mathematics. And what I did above isn't semantic tricks - it's precisely how many mathematical concepts are defined - in terms of *properties*. The unit impulse is a distribution such that, when integrated over its entire domain, is unity. And I consider it to be a lot more "unreal" than imaginaries, yet it forms the basis of real-world signal processing.

#### But what's it mean for *my* data?

It depends.

If the data is provided in complex form, odds are, it was fed through stages of processing to end up that way, and said processing determines the interpretation. [I/Q data](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/In-phase_and_quadrature_components), for example, can be used to efficiently transmit two independent signals, or one and describe its amplitude and phase - positive and negative frequencies have no meaning here.

Worse yet, "positives" can lose their original meaning entirely - the Fourier transform is fundamentally a numeric manipulation, it need not come with any "meaning" attached. This can happen with a frequency shift to "baseband" (f=0), for example, that's done for engineering purposes. Then the interpretation could be efficient compression, sparse encoding, or other.

Either data must be measured as complex as in above examples, or the processing of real-valued data must involve operations that distinguish between positive and negative frequencies, as with JTFS.

#### Is "negative frequency" fundamentally about *frequency*? Or is it about rotation, or time evolution? Mathematically?

[Covered in this article.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87997/50076)

#### Notes

1. The intro GIF is [JTFS 2D wavelets](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86013/50076)! It also provides the explanation that was "assumed" at top of this article.
2. The Fourier coefficient results of my Earth-sun example ignore the traversal about Saggitarius A*; instead, the "axis of evolution" is time. It *could* be made with respect to the traversal instead, with Earth's orbit projected into the 2D plane perpendicular to the sun's velocity.

Comment: Hi OLGD from the past. You forgot that complex numbers are phasors, whose intensities point and combine perpendicular to rotation, not tangent. You missed this because you're not very smart. Luckily, this post isn't invalidated. You will fix the other one tomorrow.

Answer (score -3):

Used to be to get the right answer for power you had to double the answer. But if you integrate from minus infinity to plus infinity you get the right answer without the arbitrary double. So they said there must be negative frequecies. But no one has ever really found them. They are therefore imaginary or at least from a physical point of view unexplained.