# DFT of real sinusoids - why sum over -$N/2$ to $N/2-1$ as opposed to $0$ to $N-1$?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, dft

I'm going through a Coursera course on signal processing, and we're just introduced to DFTs.

We are told that if you have a complex sinusoidal signal 
$x[n]$ where $n=0,1...\ N-1$, its DFT is given as

$$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$$

And this makes sense to me. Because $x[n]$ has $N$ samples. You take each one, multiply it with the sample of a basis function, essentially taking the dot product of the signal with the basis function, and you get how much of that frequency is present in the input signal.

But we are told that if you have a real sinusoidal signal $y[n]$ where $n=0,1...\ N-1$, then the DFT is given as

$$X[k]=\sum_{n=-N/2}^{N/2-1} y[n] e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$$

**My question:** ***Why do we sum over the different values?*** What is the intuition and explanation behind this?

I'm not even sure what $y[-N/2]$ would mean.

Is the $-N/2^{th}$ sample the same as the $N/2^{th}$ sample because we assume the input signal is periodic? Even if so, why is taking the DFT summation over such a range beneficial? We could also do this for complex sinusoidal signals since they're periodic too right? What's the advantage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DFT ([Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)) of an $N$-point sequence $\left\{x[n]\right\}$ is given as:
$$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j2\pi kn/N}, \quad k=0, 1, \ldots, N-1\tag{1}$$

If we assume the sequence $\left\{x[n]\right\}$ and its DFT are complex, they can be expressed as follows (with the subscript $r$ and $i$ for real and imaginary part respectively):

\begin{align}
x[n] &= x_r[n]+jx_i[n], \quad 0\leq n\leq N-1\\
X[k] &= X_r[k]+jX_i[k], \quad 0\leq k\leq N-1
\end{align}

With a bit of algebra and using equation $(1)$, you get:

\begin{align}
X_r[k] &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left[ x_r[n]\cos\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}
\right)+x_i[n]\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}
\right)\right]\\
X_i[k] &= -\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left[ x_r[n]\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}
\right)-x_i[n]\cos\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}
\right)\right]
\end{align}
If the sequence $\left\{x[n]\right\}$ is real-valued, this means $ x[n]=x_r[n]$ as $x_i[n]=0$. The DFT will then be expressed as:

$$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]\left[\cos\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}
\right)-j\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}
\right)\right]\tag{2}$$

And it can be shown from equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ that for these real-valued signals:

$$X(N-k)=X^*(k)=X(-k)\tag{3}$$

- From the above results, it suffices to compute the DFT for half of the values of $k$ to get the full characteristic of the spectrum. From the $N$ values you compute **less** (roughly half) $k$ values. The boundaries of the summation are still the same, it still goes from $n=0$ to $N-1$ but your $k$'s shouldn't go up to $N-1$ as it will be a waste of resources. 
  $$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}y[n] e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$$

  For $N$ even, $ 0\leq k \leq N/2$ suffices. With the results from equation $(3)$ you can get the remaining values from $N/2 + 1$ to $N-1$ or from $-N/2 + 1$ to $-1$.
- You have $ 0\leq n \leq N$. So, $y[-N/2]$ does not exist and $y[N/2]$ is the value of your sequence $\left\{y[n]\right\}$ at $n=N/2$ (if $N$ is even).
- However, for a real even sequence $\left\{y[n]\right\}$, the DFT $X[-N/2]$ equals $X[N/2]$ and this is the value at Nyquist.
- Also note from equation $(3)$ that if $N$ is even, $X[0]$ and $X[N/2]$ must be real, and if $N$ is odd $X[0]$ is still real but you don't have a frequency bin at exactly $N/2$. Equation $(3)$ applies for real-valued sequences, what has been concluded from that equation doesn't apply for strictly complex-valued sequences. The advantage is that you've saved computations by computing only half of what you need to compute.

Comment: Hi Giles  

Thanks for taking the time out for your elaborate answer. I have a few follow up questions:  
Q1. From your second point, you say that $y[-N/2]$ doesn't exist. And I agree with that. But then the course slides use the second equation that I posted in the question. How does one interpret $y[n]$ when $n=-N/2$ in that equation?  

Q2. The sole purpose of deriving $(3)$ in your answer is just to realize that the computations can be halved and leverage that fact right?

Comment: Q3. Is there any particular benefit of considering a negative frequency like X(-k) as opposed to just looking at it traditionally as X(N-k)?

Comment: BTW sorry about the formatting. How do you add newlines to comments? Ending the line with two spaces doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also, since your explanation was simple and clear, I'd appreciate it if you could look at another couple of questions:
[DFT of discrete signals, why do we only analyze frequency bins equal to number of input samples?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/dft-of-discrete-signals-why-do-we-only-analyze-frequency-bins-equal-to-number-o) and [Why are the basis functions for DFT so?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29774/why-are-the-basis-functions-for-dft-so)

Comment: @GrowinMan . 

`Q1.` We're still doing a $N$-point DFT of $y[n]$. One could write $y[-N/2]$ as you did and do half the summation **but only if** a change of variable to let's $n=m-N/2$ was done and also that $y[n]$ is symmetric such that $y[n]=y[N-n]$. If there was a change of variables that would apply to the $n$ exponent on the exponential. But strictly going from the definition $y[-N/2]$ is undefined.

Comment: `Q2.` Yes, not only that but also that $\left|X(N-k)\right| = \left|X(k)\right|$ and $\angle X(N-k) = -\angle X(k)$, and also see that for certain $k$ values $X(k)$ are real (not complex) values. 

`Q3.` There is no benefit in doing so, as the spectrum characteristics can be deducted from half of the values. Most of spectra you'll encounter in textbooks are single-side because of the symmetry. And there is no actual physical meaning to negative frequencies, see [this post](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/431/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-negative-frequencies) and comments.

Comment: I haven't tried the line spacing in comments yet. But there is this [nice tutorial on MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you may wanna look at. Thanks, I'll look at the other questions.

Comment: also, I'm sure something is off with the following, but I can't figure what. Picking up from your equation JUST before $(2)$:

\begin{align}
\
X_i[k] &= -\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left[ x_r[n]\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}
\right)-x_i[n]\cos\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}
\right)\right]
\\But\qquad tan\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{N}\right) = \frac{x_i[n]}{x_r[n]}
\end{align}

So does $X_i[k]=0$ all the time?

Comment: @GrowinMan , If $\left\{x[n]\right\}$ is real-valued, this means $ x[n]=x_r[n]$ as $x_i[n]=0$. And $X_r [k]$ and $X_i[k]$ have both of them $x_r[n]$ and $x_i[n]$. So, for a real-valued $\left\{x[n]\right\}$ you still have both $X_r [k]$ and $X_i[k]$ but their decomposition contain **only** $x[n]=x_r[n]$, which is what you get in equation $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The DFT is one and the same as the DFS.  The DFT maps a discrete and periodic sequence of values with period $N$, that is

$$x[n] = x[n+N] \quad \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

to another discrete and periodic sequence

$$X[k] = X[k+N] \quad \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

and the iDFT maps it back.  the discreteness in one domain causes the periodicity in the other domain, and since the mapping is [1-to-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), you can say that periodicity in one domain causes discreteness in the other.  both periodic sequences are fully defined by $N$ complex numbers and a practical iDFT and DFT maps those two finite-length sets of numbers back and forth to each other.

Although not commonly done, it's perfectly okay to generalize the DFT and iDFT to be

$$ X[k] = \sum\limits_{n=n_0}^{n_0+N-1} x[n] \ e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N} $$

$$ x[n] = \frac1N \sum\limits_{k=k_0}^{k_0+N-1} X[k] \ e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} $$

$n, n_0, k, k_0$ can be any integers.

so the choice of $k_0 = -\frac{N}{2}$ comes from the convenience of pairing $X[-k]$ to $X[k]$.  since, in general

$$ X[k] = \Re\{X[k]\} + j \Im\{X[k]\} $$

and if $\Im\{x[n]\}=0$ for all $n$, then

$$ X[-k] = X^*[k] = \Re\{X[k]\} - j \Im\{X[k]\} $$

then you can say, about reconstructing $x[n]$, that if $N$ is even

$$ x[n] = \frac1N \sum\limits_{k=-\frac{N}{2}}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} X[k] \ e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} $$

if $N$ is odd, then

$$ x[n] = \frac1N \sum\limits_{k=-\frac{N-1}{2}}^{\frac{N-1}{2}} X[k] \ e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} $$

and you can sorta plug in $n = f_\text{s} t$ to reconstruct bandlimited $x(t)$ outa $x[n]$.

in the $N$ even case, then you have an extra term at Nyquist, the $k=-\frac{N}{2}$ term,  for that you cannot know both the amplitude and phase of that sinusoid.  you must assume one or the other.  often people only keep the $\cos(\pi f_\text{s} t)$ term at Nyquist.

$$ \begin{align}
x[n] & = \frac1N \sum\limits_{k=-\frac{N}{2}}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} X[k] \ e^{j 2 \pi nk/N}  \\
 & = \frac1N \left( X[0] + X[N/2] \cos(\pi n) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} X[k] e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} \ + \ X[-k] e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N} \right) \\
 & = \frac1N \left( X[0] + X[N/2] \cos(\pi n)  \right) \\ & \quad + \frac1N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} (\Re\{X[k]\} + j \Im\{X[k]\}) e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} \ + \ (\Re\{X[k]\} - j \Im\{X[k]\}) e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N} \\
 & = \frac1N \left( X[0] + X[N/2] \cos(\pi n)  \right) \\ & \quad + \frac1N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} 2\Re\{X[k]\} \frac{e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} + e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N}}{2} + j (2j) \Im\{X[k]\} \frac{e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} - e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N}}{2j}   \\
 & = \frac1N \left( X[0] + X[N/2] \cos(\pi n)  \right) \\ & \quad + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} \Re\{X[k]\} \frac{e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} + e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N}}{2} - \Im\{X[k]\} \frac{e^{j 2 \pi nk/N} - e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N}}{2j}   \\
 & = \frac1N \left( X[0] + X[N/2] \cos(\pi n)  \right) \\ & \quad + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} \Re\{X[k]\} \cos(2 \pi nk/N) - \Im\{X[k]\} \sin(2 \pi nk/N)   \\
\end{align} $$

for $N$ odd, you can go through the same song and dance, but there is no Nyquist term and it comes out as

$$ x[n] = \frac1N X[0] + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \Re\{X[k]\} \cos(2 \pi nk/N) - \Im\{X[k]\} \sin(2 \pi nk/N) $$

---

for odd $N$, all of these discrete-time sinusoids can be understood as a properly-sampled **bandlimited** periodic, continuous-time, real signal, $x(t)$:

$$ x[n] \triangleq x(nT) = x(n/f_\text{s}) $$

or setting $ n \leftarrow f_\text{s} t $

$$ x(t) = \frac1N X[0] + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \Re\{X[k]\} \cos(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t) - \Im\{X[k]\} \sin(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t) $$

but when $N$ is even, the Nyquist term is a little more ambiguous:

$$ \begin{align}
x(t) & = \frac1N \left( X[0] + X[N/2] \cos(2 \pi (f_\text{s}/2) t)  \right) \\ & \quad + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} \Re\{X[k]\} \cos(2 \pi k f_\text{s} t) - \Im\{X[k]\} \sin(2 \pi k f_\text{s} t)   \\
 & = \frac1N \left( X[0] + X[N/2] \cos(2 \pi (f_\text{s}/2) t)  \right) \\ & \quad + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} \Re\{X[k]\} \cos(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t) - \Im\{X[k]\} \sin(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t)   \\
 & = \frac1N \left( X[0] + X[N/2] \cos(2 \pi (f_\text{s}/2) t) +  A_x \sin(2 \pi (f_\text{s}/2) t)  \right) \\ & \quad + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} \Re\{X[k]\} \cos(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t) - \Im\{X[k]\} \sin(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t)   \\
\end{align} $$

where $A_x$ can be any number, because that term will be zero at the sampling instances, when $t = nT = n/f_\text{s}$.

looking at it from a magnitude/phase POV, for $N$ odd

$$ x(t) = \frac{X[0]}{N} + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N-1}{2}} |X[k]| \cos(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t + \arg\{X[k]\})  $$

and for $N$ even

$$ \begin{align} x(t) & = \frac{X[0]}{N} +  \frac{X[N/2]}{N \cos(\theta)} \cos(2 \pi (f_\text{s}/2) t + \theta) \\ & \quad + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} |X[k]| \cos(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t + \arg\{X[k]\}) \end{align}$$

where 
$$ \Re\{X[k]\} = |X[k]| \cos(\arg\{X[k]\}) $$
$$ \Im\{X[k]\} = |X[k]| \sin(\arg\{X[k]\}) $$

or 
$$ |X[k]| = \sqrt{\Re\{X[k]\}^2 + \Im\{X[k]\}^2} $$
$$ \arg\{X[k]\} = \operatorname{atan2}(\Im\{X[k]\}, \Re\{X[k]\}) $$

and $\theta$ is the phase of the Nyquist component and can be any real value except $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}+ m \pi$ for integer $m$ (because you cannot divide by zero).  the samples $x[n] \triangleq x(n/f_\text{s})$ will come out the same regardless of the phase of the Nyquist component as long as the amplitude of the component is adjusted accordingly by dividing by $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: For real-valued sequences with $N$ even, you know both $\left|X[N/2]\right|$ and $\angle  X[N/2]$. And $\angle  X[N/2]=0$.

Comment: $X[N/2]$ could be negative.  then the angle is not zero.  but the sinusoidal component at Nyquist could have *virtually* any phase, as long as the amplitude is adjusted so that it hits the same alternating points.  a pure $\sin()$ term is not possible at Nyquist if $X[N/2] \ne 0$.

Comment: I don't agree with your statement that at $k=-N/2$ "*you cannot know both the amplitude and phase*" for real-valued sequences with $N$ even. Not only $\angle X[-N/2]=0$, but also $\angle X[0]$, $\angle X[N/2]$, and $\angle X[\pm N]$. And you also know their amplitudes.

Comment: sorry, you're wrong on all counts. if $x[n]$ is real, then we know that $X[N/2]$ and $X[0]$ are real as well.  but they can be positive or negative.  how does that affect their angles?  also try $$ \begin{align} x(t) & = \frac{X[0]}{N} +  \frac{X[N/2]}{N \cos(\theta)} \cos(2 \pi (f_\text{s}/2) t + \theta) \\ & \quad + \frac2N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{N}{2}-1} |X[k]| \cos(2 \pi (k/N) f_\text{s} t + \arg\{X[k]\}) \end{align}$$
 where $t = n/f_\text{s}$. do the samples come out differently as $\theta$ varies? this is why there is aliasing unless the sample rate **exceeds** twice the bandwidth.

Comment: forgot to qualify the rhetorical question i asked in the previous comment.  other than $\theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\pm \frac{3\pi}{2}$ or $\pm \frac{5\pi}{2}$, etc., do the samples come out differently as $\theta$ varies?  so we have a term in the continuous-time signal: $$ \frac{X[N/2]}{N \cos(\theta)} \cos(2 \pi (f_\text{s}/2) t + \theta) $$ at precisely the Nyquist frequency. if you know the angle $\theta$, then you know the amplitude $\frac{X[N/2]}{N \cos(\theta)}$, or vise versa.  but you don't know both.

Comment: What I am saying is that for certain values of $k$ it is possible to know both the amplitude **and** the phase of $X[k]$. Which your statement seem to refute.

Comment: what i am saying is that you do not know and you cannot know **both** the amplitude **and** the phase of a frequency component with frequency precisely at Nyquist.  you can assume one and calculate the other based on that assumption.  for all $|k| < N/2$, you know everything you need for each real sinusoid from the magnitude and angle of $X[k]$.  but not at $|k| = N/2$.  there, you don't know enough about the sinusoid to describe it completely.  you know *something* about it, but not everything, and the reason is because of aliasing.

Comment: Months later I'm reading this again and I'm still a little lost on the Math, so I'm going to try asking for clarifying questions. What do you mean by `the discreteness in one domain causes the periodicity in the other `

Comment: @GrowinMan - when you have a continuous-time function $x(t)$ and you uniformly **sample** it by multiplying it by $$ s(t) = T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-nT) $$, that will cause the spectrum or Fourier Transform of $x(t)$, which we call "$X(f)$" to be made into a periodic function of $f$.  $$ \mathcal{F} \{ x(t) \cdot s(t) \} = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X(f - k f_s) $$ where $f_s = \frac{1}{T}$  that is discretely sampled in $t$ and periodic in $f$.  and this can be turned around the other way.