# Auditory models which are not human

Tags: preprocessing

I am doing a machine learning project and I'm interested in the different pre-processing techniques which can be applied to audio data. In particular, I am interested in comparing a human auditory model (basically pre-process my data into features which mimic how humans perceive sound) and a non-human auditory model. I know for example that the [Mel Spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) is a human-auditory model. Or the [multi resolution cochleagram](https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Ewang.77/papers/CWW.taslp14.pdf). But what are the ones that are not human auditory? I suppose an example is the [short-time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)? Or the PCM data?

> What would be other examples?

Comment: [JTFS](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78623/50076) is mammalian. Code to be released. Since CWT-based models are good human auditory models, and it is significantly different from STFT, I suppose you could call STFT "non-human".

Comment: If you say "non-human" do you mean other live forms or mathematical (non-biological) algorithms?

Comment: @Hilmar yes, exactly, mathematical (non-biological). Do you know others of the types?