# One-sided bandwidth of the Gaussian filter

Tags: filters, gaussian, bandwidth

As defined in the [CCSDS](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/413x0g3e1.pdf) (section 3.1.2), the impulse response of the Gaussian filter is given by

$$
h(t) = \frac{1}{\sigma T \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2T^2}}
$$
where
$$
\sigma = \frac{\sqrt{\ln{2}}}{2 \pi B T}
$$
$B$ is defined as

> one-sided 3-dB bandwidth of the filter with impulse response $h(t)$.

What is exactly the meaning of "one-sided" in this context? What would be $B$ if it were the two-sided version instead?

A good reference can be found in [Gaussian Pulse – FFT & PSD in Matlab & Python](https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2014/07/generating-basic-signals-gaussian-pulse-and-power-spectral-density-using-fft/).

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to tell us where you found this.  Either a link, or a book or article citation.  If you can pull out a short excerpt, please quote it.  This probably means the bandwidth from 0Hz to the 3dB point, but without more context, I cannot say.

Comment: @TimWescott done.

Comment: Typically that's just a convention: one-sided means "distance from the center frequency (0dB) to the -3 dB frequency". Two-sided would be the difference between the two -3dB points (below and above the center), so  twice the one-sided bandwidth for a symmetrical filter (which the Gaussian is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's a document that pertains to communications, where it makes sense to talk about signals that have [negative frequencies](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/431/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-negative-frequencies), they're drawing a distinction between the one-sided bandwidth (from 0Hz to the positive-frequency $-3\mathrm{dB}$ point) vs. the two-sided bandwidth (from one $-3\mathrm{dB}$ point to the other).

If you haven't encountered doing signal processing with complex-valued signals (or, strictly, inphase/quadrature signal pairs), then the one-sided bandwidth, for a lowpass filter, is what you would call the "perfectly ordinary bandwidth".  If you *are* building a radio system that translates some chunk of spectrum down to baseband with an I/Q demodulator, then -- because you have both inphase and quadrature parts -- it suddenly not only makes sense to have different signal components at positive vs. negative frequencies, but it also makes sense to have filters whose response is asymmetric around $0 \mathrm{Hz}$.  For such filters, you care about the two-sided bandwidth.

In this particular case, the modulation signal is purely real, so the lowpass Gaussian filter is, of necessity, symmetrical around $0 \mathrm{Hz}$, so the one-sided bandwidth is the most sensible specification for it.

Comment: This signal converted to bandpass and centered at the frequency $f_c$, would have a bandwidth equals to $2B$, which is $[f_c-B, f_c+B]$, right? Can I conclude that the bandpass signal have twice the bandwidth of its lowpass equivalent?